# Yahoo Finance. Search by name

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I can get info by symbol using RQL.

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")
```

How can I create search by company name?

Answer (score 0):

There was this [webservice](https://github.com/josuebrunel/myql/blob/master/myql/contrib/finance/stockscraper/stockretriever.py#L97) before, but it seems to be down. I haven't found another one unfortunately